# export data to xls using javascript with images and style formating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i stuck in a task where i have to export data to excel file with style formating and images using javascript. I am working with angularjs.
i tried lots of example but not able to find the exact excel.

thanks in advance

Comment: did you look at https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport

Comment: which server side you are using

Comment: hello Quince
i tried this one but got confused how to use this.

Comment: hello Nidhish Krishnan
I am using node.js as server side.

Comment: what i meant is that whether are you using java/.net/php like anything

Comment: hey @NidhshKrishnan i am using JavaScript with AngularJs

Comment: since i have faced the similar problem for downloading a xls file, there what i did is that i am having a html table which i converted into json and send it to server side (java) through ajax, at the server side using this json i created a xls and returned the outstream back to client side where it was been downloaded

Comment: are you using any Spring or Jersey Rest Service

Comment: no i am not using any type of service to export.
Can you please help me with code you use on server side.

Comment: means you are having a html table like that you have shown in the picture, and you want the same thing to be downloaded as xls

Comment: that is the sample i want after download and yes i have all data that has to be export to xls. but prob is that how to impliment style and img in that